Angular 17 external configuration
I am building a standalone Angular 17 app and I have come to the point where I want to have an external configuration file, where I could place the Rest API URL for example. I searched the web and found an approach with the APP_INITIALIZER token and tried it but it does not behave as expected. When I export the project using "ng build" and place it to a nginx server, the configuration is loaded successfully. The problem is that if I want to change the values inside the config.json, nothing happens. Even if I restart the nginx server, the values are still the ones from the first start. It is like the initialization works only the first time the app is started and then it is cached or stored somehow. All the existing sources I found online use a @NgModule decorator for older Angular versions, but in Angular 17 I do not think I need one? Are there other preferrable approaches for external configuration in Angular?
Here is some code:
main.ts
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig).catch((err) => console.error(err));

app.config.ts
function initConfigService(configService: ConfigService): () => Observable<any> {
  return () => configService.loadConfig();
}

export const provideConfigService = (): Provider => {
  const provider: (Provider) =
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    deps: [ConfigService],
    useFactory: initConfigService,
    multi: true
  };
  return provider;
};

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes), provideClientHydration(), provideAnimationsAsync(), provideHttpClient(
    withInterceptors([authInterceptor]), withFetch()
  ), provideConfigService()]
};

configService.ts
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConfigService {
  _apiUrl: string = '';
  _enableFeatureX: boolean = false;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }

  loadConfig(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get("../assets/config.json").pipe(
      tap((data: any) => {
        this._apiUrl = data.apiUrl;
        this._enableFeatureX = data.enableFeatureX;
      })
    );
  }

  getApiURL(): string {
    return this._apiUrl;
  }

  getEnableFeatureX(): boolean {
    return this._enableFeatureX;
  }
}


can you check what in the devtools what the network request shows for the config file ?

I do not see a request for the config file in the devtools..?

Are you reloading your app ? Or do you expect it to update from itself ?!

I restart the nginx server and then refresh browser page. When I try to manually fetch config.json resource from the browser, I get the new one, but the refreshed app still uses the old one.

this sounds strange. Try to add some console.log in loadConfig, to see if this function is invoked and also inside the tap

Just a wild guess, but you could just cache bust the asset file like so!
Cache Busting
Either the server / browser or service worker might cache the file and cause the issue!
  loadConfig(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(`../assets/config.json?v=${Math.random().toString().substring(2)}`).pipe(
      tap((data: any) => {
        this._apiUrl = data.apiUrl;
        this._enableFeatureX = data.enableFeatureX;
      })
    );
  }


This worked, but I also found that without it, I just need to access the app in incognito mode and just close it and open it anew on every config change and everything was fine.
